# Django :Suggestion for django model

Tags: django, orm, django-models, tags

I am using django models to create my database .

here is my User Class

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = False)   
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = here what to do ?
```

now i am planning to add tags for User so that user can select the tags (it can be more then one also )
Here is my Tags Class

```
Class Tags(models.Model)

   tag = models.CharField()
```

my question is which relation should i use for the reference Tags from User table (Foreign key or Manytomany )

Note: In future i will search the  users based on tags so please suggest me the better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ManytoMany relationship: different users may use the same tags and a single `User` will have several tags:

```
tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tags, verbose_name="list of tags")
```

Anyway, you don't have to implement a Model for the `User`, there is a User model that comes with django. See the docs:

- [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)
- [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter12/)

Comment: Actually i am using django models just to create the database so i am using my own model

Comment: one more thing why verbose_name we use actually ?

Comment: It is "A human-readable name for the object, If this isn't given, Django will use a munged version of the class name: CamelCase becomes camel case"